# Removing Certain character of a element from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If I have a list such as

```
List1 = ['I- m', 'I-m', 'I- m-', 'I@ am']
L2=[]
for l1 in list1:
    L2.append(l1.strip('@-'))
```

How do I remove `-` or `@` if it is connected to either word seperated by space. For example I would have to remove `-@` from item 0, 2 an 3 but not 1 because I-m is connected and is a same word.

Item 0, 2, and 3 have space between them.

The result should look like this:

```
L2=['I m','I-m', 'I m', 'I am']
```

However, I can remove @ from 2nd word of a item. I am unable to remove - from the first word of any item.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kasramvd, I have actually tried several. I tried checking SO for this problem. I used strip function to strip the symbol. It strips @ at the back but doesnt remove - in the 1st word of the item. Please check the edited portion

Comment: @Sam did you try the `replace` function?

Comment: @ problem with replace function is it replaces every - and @ from the list. It will mess up the 1st element as well. It will replace - from the 1st element even thought I don't want to replace - in that instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to replace your characters with an empty string if there was a space in your string:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'[@-]',r'',i) if ' ' in i else i for i in List1]
['I m', 'I-m', 'I m', 'I am']
```

Comment: Thank you  Kasramvd. This and Valijon's both answer works. I didn't know I could apply regex in the list. I am learning a lot. I fixed Valijon's expression to add @.

Comment: @Sam Welcome, You can also use `str.translate` for such tasks.

Comment: Alternatively with a non-regex approach: `[s.replace(': ', '').replace('@ ', '') for s in List1]`

Comment: No. If item endswith `@` or `-`, will not replace

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to iterate a list and apply regex

```
import re
map(lambda x: re.sub("[\-@]([ ]|$)", "\g<1>",x), ['I- m', 'I@m', 'I-m', 'I- m-', 'I@ am'])
['I m', 'I@m', 'I-m', 'I m', 'I am']
```

Comment: Yep. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Thank you @Kasramvd and Valijon for helping me